# How can I troubleshoot my azure VM costs?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, price

I have a linux VM on azure, it's `Standard A1 v2 (1 vcpus, 2 GiB memory)` and forecast costs when choosing size are 25.24 euros, but after almost a month it costed me 86 euros. Cost analysis section says, that storage costed 50 euros. I don't have any disks except for this VM.
What can I do? How can I minimize costs?

Comment: change to a smaller disk / vhd rather than ssd

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio to change disk type I have to create new disk and delete old, right?

Comment: if it's the SO disk, then yes

Comment: I changed from Standard SSD to Standard HDD without deleting :)

Answer (score 0):

the forecast cost might be correct for the vm resource itself BUT you have to add the disk cost. These cost may vary depending on the option you choose:

- Standart HDD
- Standart SSD
- Premium SSD
- Ultra Disk
- LRS oder GRS

I suggest you check the [Azure pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) for your specific disk configuration. This will give you the exact price!
Jan